# Visual Studio/RAD support for coding directly in IL?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, cil, il

For the longest time I've been curious to code directly in Intermediate Language as an academic endeavour, to gain a better understanding of what's happening "under the hood".

Does anybody provide Visual Studio support for *IL in the form of: project templates, IntelliSense and RAD tool integration?

**Edits**: I don't mean restricted to out-of-the-box features. For example, I can download Visual Studio extensions to support [Python](http://ironpython.net/), [COBOL](http://www.netcobol.com/products/Fujitsu-NetCOBOL-for-.NET/overview), etc. Looking for the same for *IL.

There is a stand-alone [Intermediate Assembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx(VS.80).aspx) tool so the ability to code and compile it already exists outside Visual Studio.

Comment: what are you trying toa achieve?

Comment: @Simon - "Curious to code directly in Intermediate Language as an academic endeavour, to gain a better understanding of what's happening "under the hood""

Comment: well there is cecil. think reflection for IL. it give you a strong typed class representation of IL that you can modify http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513319/mono-cecil-documentation-and-tutorials

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wanting the same thing for a long time, I finally decided to make one. It supports syntax highlighting for IL files (.il) and includes projects with full debugging support for C#, F# and Visual Basic that support embedding and calling IL code directly.

[IL Support extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44034a7b-143d-4b51-b7bc-99aa656ba137)

Enjoy!

Comment: Installed it and gave it a quick try. Good stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out the [#develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) IDE, its not Visual Studio - they have a project template and keyword highlighting but no intellisense for IL (last time I checked).

You can also try [ILIDE#](http://nida.se/dahlog/?p=41) but I can't seem to get the thing running anymore.  It was built back in .net 1.0 days I believe so it's probably too old.

If you have time and really want to learn it - you could always write an extension for Visual Studio - that would be super cool if you did :)

Comment: Thanks. It's an alternate solution that works for me and provides more support for IL than Visual Studio does.

Comment: Good luck and let me know if you decide to extend VS for IL ... I'd like to do it but just don't have the time.

Comment: Just installed #develop. It has an IL Console application Solution. I'm creating HelloWorld IL. Awesome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. VS can't even compile MSIL (which, by the way, is now called CIL: Common Intermediate Language since the CLR was standardized).

Comment: If support exists, wouldn't it come in the form of Visual Studio calling the IL assembler or something akin to it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, the IL assembler can compile it, but Visual Studio can't call that natively. Of course you can setup a custom build rule for it, but you can setup custom build rules to do anything.

Comment: Update: A Visual Studio extension has recently become available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9755184/179972

Answer (score 0):

Not a "real" support per se, but you *can* get `ilasm` to generate PDB files out of `.il` files when it builds the assembly. You'll be able to use Visual Studio to debug the assembly, set breakpoints, ....